# How do I match to a pattern like `&(&usize, &u32)`?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Let's say I have vectors of primes and powers:

```
let mut primes: Vec<usize> = ...;
let mut powers: Vec<u32> = ...;
```

It is a fact that `primes.len() == powers.len()`.

I'd like to return to the user a list of primes which have a corresponding power value of 0 (this code is missing proper refs and derefs):

```
primes.iter().zip(powers)
    .filter(|(p, power)| power > 0)
    .map(|(p, power)| p)
    .collect::<Vec<usize>>()
```

The compiler is complaining a lot, as you might imagine. In particular, the `filter` is receiving arguments of type `&(&usize, &u32)`, but I am not correctly de-referencing in the pattern matching. I have tried various patterns the compiler suggests (e.g. `&(&p, &power)`, which is the one that makes the most sense to me), but with no luck. How do I correctly perform the pattern matching so that I can do the `power > 0` comparison without issue, and so that I can collect in the end a `Vec<usize>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
primes.iter().zip(powers)
```

`iter()` iterates by reference, so you get `&usize` elements for primes. OTOH `.zip()` calls `.into_iter()` which iterates owned values, so powers are `u32`, and these iterators combined iterate over `(&usize, u32)`. Technically, there's nothing wrong with iterating over such mixed type, but the inconsistency may be confusing. You can use `.into_iter()` or `.iter().cloned()` on primes to avoid the reference, or call `.zip(powers.iter())` to get both as references.

Second thing is that `.filter()` takes items by reference `&(_,_)` (since it only "looks" at them), and `.map()` by owned value `(_,_)` (which allows it to change and return it).

For small values like integers, you'd usually use these methods like this:

```
.filter(|&item| …)
.map(|item| …)
```

Note that in closures the syntax is `|pattern: type|`, so in the example above `&item` is equivalent to:

```
.filter(|by_ref| {
   let item = *by_ref;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

That works:

```
fn main() {
  let primes: Vec<usize> = vec![2, 3, 5, 7];
  let powers: Vec<u32> = vec![2, 2, 2, 2];

  let ret = primes.iter().zip(powers.iter())
            .filter_map(|(p, pow)| { // both are refs, so we need to deref
                if *pow > 0 {
                    Some(*p)
                } else {
                    None
                }
            })
            .collect::<Vec<usize>>();

  println!("{:?}", ret);
}
```

Note that I also used `powers.iter()` which yields elements by reference. You could also use `cloned()` on both iterators and work with values.

Answer (score 0):

`filter_map` can be used well with `match`:

```
.filter_map(|(p, pow)| match pow > &0 {
    true => Some(*p),
    _ => None,
})
```

*or*

```
.filter_map(|(p, pow)| match pow.cmp(&0) {
    Greater => Some(*p),
    _ => None,
})
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d8da880acb9989594cec70d088f05753)